# "Querying Team Projects has encountered a ...... Connect refused: connect"

Tags: tfs, ibm-integration-bus

IIB (IBM Integration Bus) won't connect to TFS (Team Foundation Server) since I got a new machine.

I try to connect to TFS, but it hangs, then I see a dialog box which says:
"Querying Team Projects has encountered a problem.  Connect refused:  connect"

I can connect to my TFS project via Team Web Access (TFS web portal).
I can connect to my TFS project via Visual Studio.
So I still have all the access required to get to my TFS project.

I use IIB to access my source code in the TFS project.  However, when troubleshooting, I tried to "Get latest" from Visual Studio.  It worked, but strangely, I didn't have to map to a local folder first.

I'm wondering if TFS Workspaces are involved here, but I took a look at mine, and it seems fine.  Can't find anything to help.  Considering wiping the Workspace, uninstalling Visual Studio and IIB, then startging from scratch.

Comment: How did you use IIB to connect to TFS? From your description, your TFS is running well. Please share your steps to use IIB to connect TFS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and apologies for the delayed response.  I thought TFS was working fine myself.  Looks like I've found the solution- please see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, newbie mistake there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears TFS was fine all along (I suspected this anyway).

I changed the Network Connection in Eclipse from "Native" to "Direct" in the Eclipse workbench, and now all is well:)